# Not able to link my public domain name to an Application under default website on IIS

Tags: iis-7, iis-10

I created an Angular application and published it on IIS 10.0 under the Default Web Site.
I can access it from the browser using htt://localhost/MyWebApp OR http://12.21.12.321/MyWebApp

> I want to link my website http://12.21.12.321/MyWebApp to a domain
> name eg.www.mywebsite.com.

I have configured the DNS A entry of my domain name to 12.21.12.321. It works fine. But the problem is it works only if I type [www.mywebsite.com/MyWebApp](http://www.mywebsite.com/MyWebApp).

But I want to map htt://localhost/MyWebApp to [www.mywebsite.com](http://www.mywebsite.com).

Is it possible without changing the publish directory to inetpub\wwwroot on my server.

I want to know if http://localhost be redirected to one specific application under the default website.

I have searched nearly 2 hours and tried few solutions, but unfortunately nothing worked so far.
Please help.

Thanks
X